# What corner case am I missing in my Rust emulation of C++'s `std::cin >>`?

Tags: rust

My plan is to write a simple method which does exactly what `std::cin >>` from the C++ standard library does:

```
use std::io::BufRead;

pub fn input<T: std::str::FromStr>(handle: &std::io::Stdin) -> Result<T, T::Err> {
    let mut x = String::new();
    let mut guard = handle.lock();
    loop {
        let mut trimmed = false;
        let available = guard.fill_buf().unwrap();
        let l = match available.iter().position(|&b| !(b as char).is_whitespace()) {
            Some(i) => {
                trimmed = true;
                i
            }
            None => available.len(),
        };
        guard.consume(l);
        if trimmed {
            break;
        }
    }
    let available = guard.fill_buf().unwrap();
    let l = match available.iter().position(|&b| (b as char).is_whitespace()) {
        Some(i) => i,
        None => available.len(),
    };
    x.push_str(std::str::from_utf8(&available[..l]).unwrap());
    guard.consume(l);
    T::from_str(&x)
}
```

The `loop` is meant to trim away all the whitespace before valid input begins. The `match` block outside the loop is where the length of the valid input (that is, before trailing whitespaces begin or `EOF` is reached) is calculated.

Here is an example using the above method.

```
let handle = std::io::stdin();
let x: i32 = input(&handle).unwrap();
println!("x: {}", x);
let y: String = input(&handle).unwrap();
println!("y: {}", y);
```

When I tried a few simple tests, the method works as intended. However, when I use this in online programming judges like the one in codeforces, I get a complaint telling that the program sometimes stays idle or that the wrong input has been taken, among other issues, which leads to suspecting that I missed a corner case or something like that. This usually happens when the input is a few hundreds of lines long.

What input is going to break the method? What is the correction?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-is-it-so-difficult-to-get-user-input-in-rust/27444/3

Comment: @shards: for more urgent/interactive questions you may want to try the Discord server: https://discord.com/invite/rust-lang

Comment: I don't see anything glaringly obvious, so without having any failing test cases I can't reproduce the problem. If you can figure out a way to reproduce it consistently, please [edit] the question to contain it. Otherwise I agree with Matthieu, you should probably ask in a channel more oriented toward quick and interactive feedback. SO is not really very good for questions with a lot of back-and-forth or brainstorming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation, I noticed a lag when reading each input, which added up as the number of inputs were increased. The function doesn't make use of a buffer. It tries to access the stream every time it needs to fill a variable, which is slow and hence the lag.

Lesson learnt: Always use a buffer with a good capacity.

However, the idleness issue still persisted, until I replaced the `fill_buf`, `consume` pairs with something like `read_line` or `read_string`.